# JavaScript code to run the Clock (date and time) four times faster

Tags: javascript, html

I am in need of virtual time (4 x current date and time). I have managed to display the running clock with the current date and time, but I am unable to the time four times faster than current time.

> For example, if the current date is 01-01-2012 00:00:00, the virtual time should
>   be 01-01-2012 00:00:04

Not only the seconds alone should get multiplied; the corresponding minutes, hours, date, month and year also should get multiplied when seconds crosses 59 virtual seconds. That is, the clock should run live with incremental of four seconds for every second with my date format.

Please see my page: http://www.chemfluence.org.in/sample.html

It's now running with the current time. I want to run this four times faster.

Please see my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function startTime()
            {
                var today = new Date();
                var h = today.getHours();
                var m = today.getMinutes();
                var s = today.getSeconds();
                // Add a zero in front of numbers<10
                m = checkTime(m);
                s = checkTime(s);
                document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
                    today.getDate() +
                    "-" +
                    (today.getMonth()+1)+"-" +
                    today.getFullYear() +
                    " "+h+":"+m+":"+s;
                t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
            }

            function checkTime(i)
            {
                if (i<10)
                {
                    i = "0" + i;
                }
                return i;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="startTime()">
        <div id="txt"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can suggest one thing. You can use event handling. Take current time. On every tick of clock add 4 seconds... Not tested, but it may work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple formula to determine the virtual time for every given time, knowing the two timestamps and the factor:

```
var virtualOrigin = Date.parse("2012-01-01T00:00:04"),
    realOrigin = Date.parse("2012-01-01T00:00:00"),
    factor = 4;

function getVirtual(time) {
    return new Date( virtualOrigin + (time - realOrigin) * factor );
}

// usage:
var now = new Date(),
    toDisplay = getVirtual(now);
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/pWmcA/2/)

Comment: Time is showing from 14-2-2016
I want to display the time from 01-01-2012 and start incrementing by 4 seconds for every second

Comment: I just have used the values from your example. If you want the counter to start with a different time, you will need to use an other origin: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pWmcA/3/)

Comment: Thanks Bergi - It works! But the example always starts from the start date only. if we run the same page tomo, it will start from the same date not the virtual date based on tomo. So i have modified it to 
function getVirtual(time) {
    return new Date( virtualOrigin + ((time - realOrigin) * factor)  +(realOrigin-start_realdate)*factor);
}

Comment: No. Just use your `startRealdate` as the `realOrigin` value (you will notice that is also mathematically equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

1. determine the current time ("START") (as timestamp -- count of seconds since 1970)
2. when displaying the clock, display (("CURRENT" - "START") * 4) + "START" instead

Comment: i am not clear on date conversions & separations. Please see my code above. i am extracting date and time separately and running the clock. how does will it increment 4 secs after every 1 second

Comment: +1. Start for the OPs example would be `31-12-2011 23:59:59.25`

Comment: @logan: look at Bergi's answer for an implementation.

Comment: @Bergi : I have implemented the soln in the same page but Time is showing from 14-2-2016
I want to display the time from 01-01-2012 and start incrementing by 4 seconds for every second
http://www.chemfluence.org.in/sample.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `setInterval` for 1 second and then add 4 seconds to the current date.

(This example just logs the time to the console, but you can easily hook it up to an HTML element.)

```
var date = new Date();

setInterval(function(){
  date = new Date(date.getTime() + 4000);
  console.log(date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
}, 1000);
```

Comment: what is the meaning of adding 4000 with gettime() and does the console.log updates the date and hours accordingly as well ?

Comment: `getTime` returns the number of milliseconds from 1/1/1970. Then you add 4000 more milliseconds to it (so 4 seconds).