# Running a Javascript Clock at 4x Speed

Tags: javascript, performance, clock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript to run the Clock (date and time) 4 times speeder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272133/javascript-to-run-the-clock-date-and-time-4-times-speeder)

I'm trying to make a clock that starts at a time value (hh:mm:ss) that I've supplied, and runs at 4x speed (for the server time of an online game that runs 4x actual time). I've modified a free clock that I found online to do this, but it only works for every other minute (try the code below to see exactly what I mean if that doesn't make sense).

```
var customClock = (function () {
    var timeDiff;
    var timeout;

    function addZ(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }

    function formatTime(d) {
        t1 = d.getHours();
        t2 = d.getMinutes();
        t3 = d.getSeconds() * 4;
        if (t3 > 59) {
            t3 = t3 - 60;
            t2 = t2 + 1;
        }
        if (t2 > 59) {
            t2 = t2 - 60;
            t1 = t1 + 1;
        }
        if (t1 > 23) {
            t1 = 0;
        }
        return addZ(t1) + ':' + addZ(t2) + ':' + addZ(t3);
    }

    return function (s) {
        var now = new Date();
        var then;

        var lag = 1015 - now.getMilliseconds();

        if (s) {
            s = s.split(':');
            then = new Date(now);
            then.setHours(+s[0], +s[1], +s[2], 0);
            timeDiff = now - then;
        }

        now = new Date(now - timeDiff);
        document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = formatTime(now);
        timeout = setTimeout(customClock, lag);
    }
}());

window.onload = function () {
    customClock('00:00:00');
};
```

Any idea why this is happening? I'm pretty new to Javascript and this is definitely a little hack-ey. Thanks

Comment: Didn't we have had that already? Can't find the question currently

Comment: I looked and couldn't find it, but if was already answered a link would be great.

Answer (score 2):

i take the orginal time and substract it from the current then multiply it by 4 and add it to the orginal time. I think that should take care or the sync problem.

```
(function(){
  var startTime = new Date(1987,08,13).valueOf() //save the date 13. august 1987
    , interval = setInterval(function() {
          var diff = Date.now() - startTime

          //multiply the diff by 4 and add to original time
          var time = new Date(startTime + (diff*4))

          console.log(time.toLocaleTimeString())
      }, 1000)
}())
```

*How to use with a custom date* (use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object)

`Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`

Comment: This works, but it makes it more difficult for me to start from a custom time, which is important. Am I missing how to integrate this into the original code?

Answer (score 0):

`var lag = 1015 - now.getMilliseconds();` is attempting to "run this again a smidge (15 ms) after the next clock tick".  Make this value smaller (divide by 4?), and this code will run more frequently.

Next up, get it to show 4x the current clock duration.  Similar problem: multiply now's details by 4 either inside or outside formatTime()

Comment: It runs just after the next tick only if you subtract the current milliseconds, otherwise it will slowly get later and later because of system lag and the extra 15ms.

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a `Clock` constructor as follows:

```
function Clock(id) {
    var clock = this;
    var timeout;
    var time;

    this.hours = 0;
    this.minutes = 0;
    this.seconds = 0;
    this.stop = stop;
    this.start = start;

    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    function stop() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    function start() {
        timeout = setTimeout(tick, 0);
        time = Date.now();
    }

    function tick() {
        time += 1000;
        timeout = setTimeout(tick, time - Date.now());
        display();
        update();
    }

    function display() {
        var hours = clock.hours;
        var minutes = clock.minutes;
        var seconds = clock.seconds;

        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : "" + hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : "" + minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : "" + seconds;

        element.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }

    function update() {
        var seconds = clock.seconds += 4;

        if (seconds === 60) {
            clock.seconds = 0;
            var minutes = ++clock.minutes;

            if (minutes === 60) {
                clock.minutes = 0;
                var hours = ++clock.hours;

                if (hours === 24) clock.hours = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create a clock and start it like this:

```
var clock = new Clock("clock");
clock.start();
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Nt5XN/