# Ongoing timer/clock that is based on system time?

Tags: javascript, html

Finding it hard to wrap my head around how to do this. I'm looking to make a clock that is a fantasy timezone and is calculated based on system time (because it needs to carry on when you are not on the webpage).

Daytime lasts from 7:00 am to 9:59 pm is 200 minutes in real time. 13 sec (real time) is 1 minute.
Nighttime lasts from 10:00pm to 6:59 am is 45 minutes in real time. 5 sec (real time) is 1 minute.

I would like to display the time in the fantasy world using html (Example: 5:43PM) but then also show how long in real time minutes until it is day/night in the fantasy world (Example: Night in 32 mins).

I'm thinking I would need to set the system time to 0 with `Date.setHours(0,0,0,0)` then work out the difference. The maths is really what is confusing me more than anything.

Comment: You cannot set system time in JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript code to run the Clock (date and time) four times faster](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14272133/1048572)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we start with a solution, let's start with some tests -- this will give definition to the eventual solution, and give us confident that we are arriving at the correct solution.

What we are ultimately after is a function; we'll call it `realTimeToGameTime`.  It takes a `Date` object, and returns an object that looks like `{ day: 0, time: '7:00 am' }`.  In your question, you don't mention whether it's important to know what day it is in the game (only what time), but not only does this seem to be a useful addition, you'll see it's important to the solution.

Now that we know what the end result looks like, we can consider some tests.  There is some point in both real time and the game time that represents a correspondence between game time and real time.  In real time, it can be any point in time we want; I'll call it `c`.  In game time, we'll arbitrarily call it 7:00 am on day 0.  This allows us to construct a timeline that gives us the inputs and outputs for our test cases (in minutes and hours/minutes):

```
  c+0m   c+100m    c+200m   c+215m   c+245m   c+345m   c+445m   c+490m
  c+0h   c+1:40h   c+3:20h  c+3:35h  c+4:05h  c+5:45h  c+7:25h  c+8:10h
---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---
  7:00a   2:30p    10:00p    1:00a   7:00a     2:30p   10:00p    7:00a
   day 0                              day 1                       day 2
```

We'll pick an arbitrary date/time -- midnight, Jan 1, 2017 -- and write our tests:

```
const y = 2017
const m = 0        // 0=Jan in JS
const d = 1
expect(realTimeToGameTime(new Date(y, m, d, 0, 0))
  .toEqual({ day: 0, time: '7:00 am' })
expect(realTimeToGameTime(new Date(y, m, d, 1, 40))
  .toEqual({ day: 0, time: '2:30 pm' })
expect(realTimeToGameTime(new Date(y, m, d, 3, 20))
  .toEqual({ day: 0, time: '10:00 pm' })   
expect(realTimeToGameTime(new Date(y, m, d, 3, 35))
  .toEqual({ day: 0, time: '1:00 am' })   
expect(realTimeToGameTime(new Date(y, m, d, 4, 50))
  .toEqual({ day: 1, time: '7:00 am' })   
expect(realTimeToGameTime(new Date(y, m, d, 5, 45))
  .toEqual({ day: 1, time: '2:30 pm' })   
expect(realTimeToGameTime(new Date(y, m, d, 7, 25))
  .toEqual({ day: 1, time: '10:00 pm' })
expect(realTimeToGameTime(new Date(y, m, d, 8, 50))
  .toEqual({ day: 2, time: '7:00 am' })
```

(In this example, I'm using Jest expect assertions; you can tailor to whatever test/assertion framework you like...just make sure it has a way to test value equality on objects.)

Now on to the solution.

When confronted with problems like this -- that can get confusing very quickly, especially when you consider all the implementation details -- it's best to look at a simplified picture that's easier to reason about.  The numbers you've chosen make it hard to understand the manipulations required because there are so many details: minutes to hours, JavaScript likes milliseconds, etc, etc.  So let's start with a simplified picture that's close to your example, but way easier to think about (don't worry: it will generalize to your specific needs).

Let's say we're only worried about hours, and that daytime in the game (7:00a-9:59p) lasts 3 hours in real time, and nighttime (10:00p-6:59a) lasts 1 hour in real-time.  In this simplified model, we only care about hours, and we have a much neater timeline:

```
  c+0h    c+1h   c+2h    c+3h   c+4h    c+5h    c+6h    c+7h   c+8h
----+-------+------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+-----
  7:00a  12:00p  5:00p  10:00p  7:00a  12:00p  5:00p  10:00p  7:00a
   day 0                         day 1                         day 2
```

The problem is easier to keep in our head now, but getting to the final solution still seems daunting.  But there's an *easy* problem embedded in the harder problem: starting at the dawn of a new day in the game world, what time is it in the real game world after after a specific real world duration?  Even simpler, let's just restrict this to one day in the game world.  Solving *that* problem is very simple.  Before we do that, though, we'll need some inputs.  Here are the relevant inputs (I am using "day" to mean a 24-hour period here, distinguishing it from "daytime"):

```
const gameDaybreak = 7
const gameDayLength = 24
const gameDaytimeLength = 15
const gameNighttimeLength = gameDayLength - gameDaytimeLength

const gameDayLengthInRealTime = 4
const gameDaytimeLengthInRealTime = 3
const gameNighttimeLengthInRealTime = 
  gameDayLengthInRealTime - gameDaytimeLengthInRealTime
```

Now we can write our function:

```
gameTimeSinceDaybreakFromRealDuration(realDuration) {
    if(realDuration > gameDayLengthInRealTime)
        throw new Error("this function only works within a single game day")
    if(realDuration <= gameDaytimeLengthInRealTime) {
        return (gameDaybreak + realDuration * gameDaytimeLength /
            gameDaytimeLengthInRealTime) % gameDayLength
    } else {
        return (gameDaybreak + gameDaytimeLength +
            (realDuration - gameDaytimeLengthInRealTime) *
                gameNighttimeLength / gameNighttimeLengthInRealTime) %
                    gameDayLength
    }
}
```

There's only one puzzle piece left: how to determine what game day it is, and when that game day started in real hours.

Fortunately, we know each game day consumes a specific amount of real-world time (in our simplified example, 4 hours).  So if we have an arbitrary correspondence date, we can simply divide the number of hours from that date by 4, and arrive at the (fractional) game day.  We simply take the floor of that to get the integer game days:

```
const c = new Date(2017, 0, 1)    // this can be anything

const realHoursSinceC = (realDate.valueOf() - c.valueOf())/1000/60/60
const gameDayFromRealDate = Math.floor(realHoursSinceC / gameDayLengthInRealTime)
```

(This function won't be exactly the same in our final implementation since we won't be using hours as our time basis.)

Finally, to find out how many (real) hours we are into the day, we can subtract out the time that represents past game days:

```
const realHoursIntoGameDay = (realDate.valueOf() - c.valueOf()) -
    gameDayFromRealDate * gameDayLengthInRealTime
```

(We could actually be a little more efficient here with these last two calculations, but this is a little clearer.)

Here's the real magic in what we've just done: we've been looking at everything as hours so it's easier to understand.  *But everything we've been doing has just been arbitrary points in time and durations in the same units*.  JavaScript likes milliseconds...so all we have to do is use milliseconds instead of hours, and we have a general solution!

One last tiny detail is we need a formatter to get the game time into a nice format:

```
function formatGameTime(gameTime) {
    const totalMinutes = gameTime/1000/60    // convert from milliseconds to minutes
    const hours = Math.floor(totalMinutes/60)
    let minutes = (totalMinutes % 60).toFixed(0)
    if(minutes.length < 2) minutes = "0" + minutes   // get that leading zero!
    return hours < 13
        ? (hours + ':' + minutes + ' am')
        : ((hours - 12) + ':' + minutes + ' pm')
}
```

Now all we have to do is put it all together:

```
realTimeToGameTime(realTime) {
    const gameDayFromRealDate = Math.floor((realTime.valueOf() - c.valueOf() /  gameDayLengthInRealTime)
    const realTimeIntoGameDay = (realTime.valueOf() - c.valueOf()) - gameDayFromRealDate *
        gameDayLengthInRealTime
    const gameTime = this.gameTimeSinceDaybreakFromRealDuration(realTimeIntoGameDay)
    return {
        day: gameDayFromRealDate,
        time: this.formatGameTime(gameTime),
    }
},
```

Finally, because I really prefer pure functions -- globals are just no good!  We can create a factory to create a specific "time mapper" (note this is using some ES2015 features):

```
function createTimeMapper(config) {
    const {
        c,
        gameDaybreak,
        gameDayLength,
        gameDaytimeLength,
        gameNighttimeLength,
        gameDayLengthInRealTime,
        gameDaytimeLengthInRealTime,
        gameNighttimeLengthInRealTime,
    } = config
    return {
        realTimeToGameTime(realTime) {
            const gameDayFromRealDate = Math.floor((realTime.valueOf() - c.valueOf()) / gameDayLengthInRealTime)
            const realTimeIntoGameDay = (realTime.valueOf() - c.valueOf()) - gameDayFromRealDate * gameDayLengthInRealTime
            const gameTime = this.gameTimeSinceDaybreakFromRealDuration(realTimeIntoGameDay)
            return {
                day: gameDayFromRealDate,
                time: this.formatGameTime(gameTime),
            }
        },

        gameTimeSinceDaybreakFromRealDuration(realDuration) {
          if(realDuration > gameDayLengthInRealTime)
            throw new Error("this function only works within a single game day")
          if(realDuration <= gameDaytimeLengthInRealTime) {
            return (gameDaybreak + realDuration * gameDaytimeLength / gameDaytimeLengthInRealTime) %
              gameDayLength
          } else {
            return (gameDaybreak + gameDaytimeLength +
              (realDuration - gameDaytimeLengthInRealTime) * gameNighttimeLength / gameNighttimeLengthInRealTime) %
                gameDayLength
          }
        },

        formatGameTime(gameTime) {
            const totalMinutes = gameTime/1000/60    // convert from milliseconds to minutes
            const hours = Math.floor(totalMinutes/60)
            let minutes = (totalMinutes % 60).toFixed(0)
            if(minutes.length < 2) minutes = "0" + minutes   // get that leading zero!
            return hours < 13
              ? (hours + ':' + minutes + ' am')
              : ((hours - 12) + ':' + minutes + ' pm')
        },
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
const timeMapper = createTimeMapper({
    new Date(2017, 0, 1),
    gameDaybreak: 7*1000*60*60,
    gameDayLength: 24*1000*60*60,
    gameDaytimeLength: 15*1000*60*60,
    gameNighttimeLength: 9*1000*60*60,
    gameDayLengthInRealTime: (245/60)*1000*60*60,
    gameDaytimeLengthInRealTime: (200/60)*1000*60*60,
    gameNighttimeLengthInRealTime: (45/60)*1000*60*60,
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code was super useful. I've been playing around with it for at least an hour now. Still struggling to get my head around it though! I can't get the time to auto update and it feels like it's going _too fast_. Maybe you can take a look and figure out what I'm doing wrong, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayjb5bm/)

Comment: I made a few changes. Apparently my initial maths was wrong and a day lasts 240 minutes (200 day time and 40 night time). The time still isn't matching up with what it should be though. The next midnight is meant to be at ~08:20am UTC.

Comment: Hi, Sarah...you're on the right track, and my answer was hasty.  I was thinking about it on my walk from work, and I have a better way to think about it, but it's way past my bed time, so an update to my answer is going to have to wait.  What I've outlined is essentially correct...but there's an easier way to look at it.  Will update soon.

Comment: No problem. Take your time, I'm just appreciative of the help. I've stayed up all night working on this so it's time for me to go to bed too I think!

Comment: I think I worked it out! The time matches up too. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oo8r0h4z/3/)

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!  Nice work!  I'm still going to update my answer, if not for you, for other people...I take pride in quality answers!

Comment: Whew!  There's an exhaustive answer for you, a little late, but it was fun to solve.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks again for all the help :D Here's the finished code if you were wondering what I was doing with it all. It's probably a bit messy and could be a lot shorter but it's working at the moment. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpREbE

Comment: Looks like a fun project!  Good luck!